# SpannableString ALIGN_BASELINE First line TextView Is Covered

Tags: android, spannablestring

If the second line don't have any text, the first line will be covered. I don't want to use ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM.

How can I fix this issue?

Here is the code:

```
 Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity, R.drawable.phone_download_can_play_icon);
 drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
 String spanTitle = title + " " +"[canPlay]";
 SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(spanTitle);
 ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
 spannable.setSpan(span, title.length() + " ".length(), spanTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

so sad, I don't have enough reputation to upload the images.

[Here is the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQjsT.jpg)

Comment: but you can post the links...

Comment: thanks for you reminding, I have already added the link. ：）